# Parse feed media group with array of children

Tags: php, xml, feed

I have this XML feed:

```
<item>
    <title>Title</title>
    <media:group>
        <media:content url="http://example.it/image.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
            <media:thumbail url="http://example.it/image.jpg" type="image/png"/>
            <media:credit>Credit</media:credit>
        </media:content>
        <media:content url="http://example.it/image2.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
            <media:thumbail url="http://example.it/image2.jpg" type="image/png"/>
            <media:credit>Credit2</media:credit>
        </media:content>
    </media:group>
</item>
```

This is my PHP code for read it:

```
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = $item->title;
}
```

No problem reading "title" item, but how can I read "url", "thumbnail", "credit" for each media:content?

**-------SOLVED-------**

```
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = $item->title;
    $gallerie = $item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')->group->content;
    foreach($gallerie as $g) {
        echo $g->attributes()['url'] ."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: what's a problem? have you tried `echo $rss->group->content->thumbail['url'];` ?

Comment: I tried (both with echo and print_r), it gives me blank. The number of media:content inside media:group is not fixed. I need something that cycles that number and print each "url", "thumbnail", ecc

Comment: Better use the namespace, not the prefix. `$gallerie = $item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')->group->content;` Prefixes can change and are optional.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!